# ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous

Tags: django

Estoy tratando de validar un formato con `format.is_valid()` para guardarlo en la DB, el formato tiene 6 variables numéricas (3 son int, 3 float y 1 tipo array), cuando corro el programa me manda el siguiente error:

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous.
> Use a.any() or a.all()
> [10/Aug/2021 21:55:51] "POST /iv_input/ HTTP/1.1" 500 115890

Soy nueva en Django, ya he intentado varias maneras de poder hacerlo, incluyendo validarlo manualmente con *Cleaned_data* pero me sale el mismo error.

Modelo:

```
class Modelo(models.Model):

    fk = models.ForeignKey(PartNumber, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null = True, blank = True) 
    a = models.IntegerField()
    b = models.IntegerField()
    c = models.IntegerField()
    d = models.DecimalField(max_digits= 5, decimal_places= 2)
    e = models.DecimalField(max_digits= 5, decimal_places= 2)
    f = models.DecimalField(max_digits= 5, decimal_places= 2)
    g = ArrayField(models.DecimalField(max_digits= 5, decimal_places= 2, blank = True), default = list)
```

Form:

```
class ModeloForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Modelo
        fields = ('fk','a','b','c','d','e','f','g')

        labels = {'fk' : ‘fk','a' : 'a','b' : 'b','c' : 'c','d' : 'd','e' : 'e','f' : 'f','g' : 'g',}       
        widgets = {
            'fk' : forms.Select(attrs = {'class':'form-control'}),
            'a' : forms.NumberInput(attrs = {'class':'form-control'}),
            'b' : forms.NumberInput(attrs = {'class':'form-control'}),
            'c' : forms.NumberInput(attrs = {'class':'form-control'}),
            'd' : forms.NumberInput(attrs = {'class':'form-control'}),
            'e' : forms.NumberInput(attrs = {'class':'form-control'}),
            'f' : forms.NumberInput(attrs = {'class':'form-control'}),
}
```

View:

```
class vista(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Modelo
    form_class = {"form": ModeloForm()}
    template_name = 'Labapp/iv_template.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('iv_input/')

    def get(self, request, *arg, **kwargs):
        model = PN
        template_name = 'Labapp/iv_template.html'
        return render(request, 'Labapp/iv_template.html', self.form_class)

    def post(self, request, *arg, **kwargs):
        post_value = request.POST.copy()
        a = post_value['a']
        b = post_value['b']
        c = post_value['c']
        d = post_value['d']
        e = post_value['e']
        f = post_value['f']

        check_empty = Modelo.objects.all()

        if check_empty.exists():
            print("hay datos")
        else:
            print("no hay datos")   
            test_class1 = TEST(a,b,c,d,e,f) 
            puntos = test_class1.uno() **NOTA: TEST.uno genera un nparray**
            class_iv = ellipsoide(puntos)
            centro = class_iv.mvee() **NOTA: ellipsoide.mvee genera un nparray**
            post_value['g'] = g

            post_value.pop('csrfmiddlewaretoken')
            iv_create_form = PostForm(post_value)

            if iv_create_form.is_valid(): **NOTA: JUSTO AQUÍ SE GENERA EL ERROR**
                iv_create_form.save()
                return render(request, 'Labapp/form_principal.html', {'pagina_title':   
                       pagina_title,'centro':post_value['centro']}) 
            else:
                print("form_is_invalid")
        return HttpResponse('<h1>XXX</h1>') **NOTA: Esto solo lo puse para hacer pruebas**
```